# Как разместить в ряд поля Django Forms?

Tags: python, html, css, django

Есть поля в джанго-формах:

```
class TimeZoneForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=countries,  widget=forms.Select(attrs= 
    {'class': 'form-control mr-mb-2', 'name': 'country'}),)

    timezone = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=timezones,  widget=forms.Select(attrs= 
    {'class': 'form-control mr-mb-2', 'name': 'timezone'}),)
```

HTML код:

```
<div class="form">
    <form action="/" method='POST' class="form-group">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Дело в том, что на странице поля формы располагаются один под другим, а мне нужно, чтобы они были в один ряд. Есть ли способ это сделать ?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы применяете опцию рендера `form.as_p`, которая преобразуется в такой вид

```
<div>
....
    <p><label for="id_country"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="country" id="id_country"></p>
    <p><label for="id_timezone"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="timezone" id="id_timezone"></p>
....
</div>
```

Вам необходимо избавиться от тегов `<p>`, которые переводят на новую строку.

Один из способов - это обработка вручную, не прибегая к методам таким как `as_p`, `as_table`, `as_ul`

```
<div class="form">
    <form action="/" method='POST' class="form-group">
        {{ form.country }}
        {{ form.timezone }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не работает( Между полями формы просто удаляется пространство

Comment: @ArnoDorian что в стилях классов?

Comment: решил эту задачу путем вставки каждого поля формы в столбцы одного ряда новой таблицы, которою я создал специально для этой формы и все получилось!